# Lost databinding of usercontrol in winforms when changing parent control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

I tryed for a lot of hours: I have a simple example with a microsoft textbox and a textbox on a usercontrol. Both with databinding to a datagrid, everythink works fine, the values change automaticly when you scroll through the datagrid.

After moving both controls on a groupbox (what changes their parent) the databindings are handled by microsofts sub BindingContext.UpdateBinding. The binding of the textbox is removed and added again, but the binding of the usercontrol gets removed, but never comes back, the databinding is dead.

Whats the matter about this?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Class1

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Dim form1 As New Form With {.Width = 800, .Height = 600, .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen}

        Dim dataGrid1 As New DataGrid With {.Width = 780, .Height = 300}
        form1.Controls.Add(dataGrid1)

        Dim textbox1 As New TextBox With {.Left = 30, .Top = 400}
        form1.Controls.Add(textbox1)

        Dim userControl1 As New UserControl1 With {.Left = 150, .Top = 397, .BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua}
        form1.Controls.Add(userControl1)

        Dim groupBox1 As New GroupBox With {.Left = 410, .Top = 320, .Height = 200, .Width = 350, .Text = "GroupBox"}
        form1.Controls.Add(groupBox1)

        Dim button1 As New Button With {.Left = 290, .Top = 400, .Text = "--->"}
        form1.Controls.Add(button1)
        AddHandler button1.Click, Sub()
                                      groupBox1.Controls.AddRange({textbox1, userControl1}) : textbox1.Top = 70 : userControl1.Top = 67
                                  End Sub

        Dim snTBL = New System.Data.DataTable("serialnumbers")
        snTBL.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("serialnumber1", GetType(String)))
        snTBL.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("serialnumber2", GetType(String)))
        For i = 0 To 5
            Dim row As DataRow = snTBL.NewRow
            row.Item("serialnumber1") = CStr(i)
            row.Item("serialnumber2") = CStr(i * 10)
            snTBL.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        dataGrid1.DataSource = snTBL

        textbox1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(textbox1.Text), snTBL, "serialnumber1")
        userControl1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(userControl1.BindingText), snTBL, "serialnumber2")

        Application.Run(form1)

    End Sub


    <System.ComponentModel.DefaultBindingProperty(NameOf(UserControl1.BindingText))>
    Public Class UserControl1
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
        Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

        Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox

        Protected Overrides Sub oncreatecontrol()

            Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
            Me.SuspendLayout()
            '
            'TextBox1
            '
            Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
            Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
            Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(103, 20)
            Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
            '
            'UserControl1
            '
            Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
            Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
            Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
            Me.Name = "UserControl1"
            Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(109, 26)
            Me.ResumeLayout(False)
            Me.PerformLayout()

        End Sub

        Public Property BindingText As String
            Get
                Return Me.TextBox1.Text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Me.TextBox1.Text = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(UserControl1.BindingText)))
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    End Class

End Class
```

Comment: I'd add `Public Sub New()` to the UserControl, where you call `InitializeComponent()`. You can rename your `Protected Overrides Sub oncreatecontrol()` in `Private Sub InitializeComponent()`. Then add `Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource(snTBL, Nothing)` and set the DataSource of the Bindings to the BindingSource (e.g.,  `userControl1.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(userControl1.BindingText), bs, "serialnumber2", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)`). That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jimi, the solution was to use BindingSource instead of binding directly to the DataTable.